# Select DataGridView row when searching

Tags: powershell, search, datagridview

I am searching through a DataGridView. The TextChanged event can find the data, but the cursor does not jump to found row/column.

This is the powershell code I am using:

```
$ColNameNow = "Name"
$SrcValue = $TextBox1.text

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $datagridview1.RowCount; $i++)
{
    if ($datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells['Name'].Value -eq "$SrcValue")
    {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Found", "Update", "Ok", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning)

        $datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index = $i            
        $datagridview1.CurrentRow = $datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells[0]            
        $datagridview1.SelectedRows[$i]         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following lines:

```
$datagridview1.CurrentRow.Index = $i            
$datagridview1.CurrentRow = $datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells[0]            
$datagridview1.SelectedRows[$i]
```

With the following:

```
$datagridview1.CurrentCell = $datagridview1.Rows[$i].Cells['Name']            
$datagridview1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = $i
```

Setting the `CurrentCell` highlights the correct cell and setting the `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` sets the selected row to be the top displayed row if possible.